# Is cudaMemcpy3DPeer supported on geforce cards?

Tags: memory, cuda, nvidia, tesla

Is it possible to use peer-to-peer memory transfer on GeForce cards or is it allowed only on Teslas? I assume cards are 2 GTX690s (each one has two GPUs on board).

I have tried copying between Quadro 4000 and Quadro 600, and it failed. I was transferring 3D arrays using `cudaMemcpy3DPeer` by filling the `cudaMemcpy3DPeerParms` struct.

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem with cards and not with the way you call `cudaMemcpyPeer`? There is no reason why it should not work on GeForces or Quadros.

Comment: ok, I will have a look at my code again, i wanted to confirm if the issue is with code or the hardware

Comment: so peer to peer copy has got nothing to do with UVA which is supported only for teslas?

Answer (score 2):

**Peer-to-peer memory copy** should work on Geforce and Quadro as well as Tesla, see the [programming guide](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-gpu-computing-documentation) for more details.

> Memory copies can be performed between the memories of two different devices.
>
> When a unified address space is used for both devices (see Unified Virtual Address
>   Space), this is done using the regular memory copy functions mentioned in Device
>   Memory.
>
> Otherwise, this is done using cudaMemcpyPeer(), cudaMemcpyPeerAsync(),
>   cudaMemcpy3DPeer(), or cudaMemcpy3DPeerAsync()

**Peer-to-peer memory access**, which is where one GPU can directly read from another GPU, requires UVA (which means 64-bit OS) and Tesla and compute capability 2.0 or higher.

> Tesla Compute Cluster Mode for Windows), on Windows XP, or on Linux, devices
>   of compute capability 2.0 and higher from the Tesla series may address each other’s
>   memory (i.e., a kernel executing on one device can dereference a pointer to the memory
>   of the other device).